# Flutter unicreators/mvvm difference between $watch and $watchFor

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm

I just installed [unicreators/mvvm](https://github.com/unicreators/mvvm) flutter library and i confused whats difference between this methods in this library and documents of this library is Chinese i can't understand me

```dart
$watch<int>(
  model.timer$,
  builder: (context, value, child) =>
      Text('${pad(value ~/ 100)}.${pad(value % 100)}'),
),
const Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
model.$watchFor<int>(
  #counter,
  builder: (context, value, child) =>
      Text('$value', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
)
```

full example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mvvm/mvvm.dart';

/// ViewModel
class MyHomePageViewModel extends ViewModel {
  final timer$ = BindableProperty.$tick(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 10), autostart: true, initial: 0);

  @override
  init() {
    super.init();
    registerProperty(#counter, BindableProperty.$value(initial: 0));
  }

  void incrementCounter() {
    updateValue<int>(#counter, (value) => value + 1);
  }
}

/// View
class MyHomePage extends View<MyHomePageViewModel> {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyHomePageViewModel createViewModel() => MyHomePageViewModel();

  pad(int value) => '$value'.padLeft(2, '0');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, MyHomePageViewModel model) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            $watch<int>(
              model.timer$,
              builder: (context, value, child) =>
                  Text('${pad(value ~/ 100)}.${pad(value % 100)}'),
            ),
            const Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
            model.$watchFor<int>(
              #counter,
              builder: (context, value, child) =>
                  Text('$value', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: model.incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// run
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter MVVM Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter MVVM Demo Home Page'),
    ));
```

Comment: @unicreators could you helo me ?